# Updating row in Gridview not saving to my database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to update the row in my `GridView` to my SQL table.   But when I change some information and click on update it then does nothing, doesn't save it to the database?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PROJECTS"].ConnectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con1.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand($"SELECT id, " +
        $"Date, " +
        $"Number, " +
        $"CustomerName, " +
        $"AccpacPcNo, " +
        $"CRMCaseNo, " +
        $"ProjectDetails, " +
        $"TechnicalResourceAssigned," +
        $"ProjectPhase, " +
        $"WorkHours, " +
        $"PlannedCompletionDate, " +
        $"Comments FROM tbl_projects WHERE ID={Request["id"]}", con1);

    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        txtProjectDate.Text = (myReader["Date"].ToString());
        txtProjectNumber.Text = (myReader["Number"].ToString());
        txtProjectCustomerName.Text = (myReader["CustomerName"].ToString());
        txtProjectAccpacNumber.Text = (myReader["AccpacPcNo"].ToString());
        txtProjectCRMCaseNumber.Text = (myReader["CRMCaseNo"].ToString());
        txtProjectDetails.Text = (myReader["ProjectDetails"].ToString());
        txtProjectTechnicalResourceAssigned.Text = (myReader["TechnicalResourceAssigned"].ToString());
        txtProjectPhase.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["ProjectPhase"].ToString());
        txtProjectWorkHours.Text = (myReader["WorkHours"].ToString());
        txtProjectPlannedCompletionDate.Text = (myReader["PlannedCompletionDate"].ToString());
        txtProjectComments.Text = (myReader["Comments"].ToString());
    }
    con1.Close();
}

protected void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PROJECTS"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE tbl_projects SET [Date] = @Date, " +
        $"[Number] = @Number, " +
        $"[CustomerName] = @CustomerName, " +
        $"[AccpacPcNo] = @AccpacPcNo, " +
        $"[CRMCaseNo] = @CRMCaseNo, " +
        $"[ProjectDetails] = @ProjectDetails, " +
        $"[TechnicalResourceAssigned] = @TechnicalResourceAssigned, " +
        $"[ProjectPhase] = @ProjectPhase, " +
        $"[WorkHours] = @WorkHours, " +
        $"[PlannedCompletionDate] = @PlannedCompletionDate, " +
        $"[Comments] = @Comments FROM tbl_Projects WHERE ID = {Request["id"]}", con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtProjectDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtProjectNumber.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", txtProjectCustomerName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccpacPcNo", txtProjectAccpacNumber.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRMCaseNo", txtProjectCRMCaseNumber.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDetails", txtProjectDetails.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TechnicalResourceAssigned", txtProjectTechnicalResourceAssigned.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectPhase", txtProjectPhase.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkHours", txtProjectWorkHours.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlannedCompletionDate", txtProjectPlannedCompletionDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", txtProjectComments.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?  It displays the correct information when I click on the row to update but just doesn't want to update.  I get no error messages or anything?

Comment: this query is vulnerable for SQL Injection

Comment: ID = {Request["id"]} in update command is null.
you have to store Request["ID"] in global variable

Comment: try to print the command query in html. and check.

Answer (score 0):

check this create gloabal variable that store **Request ID** then use ID in other Events or function.

```
private static string _REQID = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _REQID = Request["id"];
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PROJECTS"].ConnectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con1.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand($"SELECT id, " +
        $"Date, " +
        $"Number, " +
        $"CustomerName, " +
        $"AccpacPcNo, " +
        $"CRMCaseNo, " +
        $"ProjectDetails, " +
        $"TechnicalResourceAssigned," +
        $"ProjectPhase, " +
        $"WorkHours, " +
        $"PlannedCompletionDate, " +
        $"Comments FROM tbl_projects WHERE ID=@ReqID", con1);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqID", _REQID );


    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        txtProjectDate.Text = (myReader["Date"].ToString());
        txtProjectNumber.Text = (myReader["Number"].ToString());
        txtProjectCustomerName.Text = (myReader["CustomerName"].ToString());
        txtProjectAccpacNumber.Text = (myReader["AccpacPcNo"].ToString());
        txtProjectCRMCaseNumber.Text = (myReader["CRMCaseNo"].ToString());
        txtProjectDetails.Text = (myReader["ProjectDetails"].ToString());
        txtProjectTechnicalResourceAssigned.Text = (myReader["TechnicalResourceAssigned"].ToString());
        txtProjectPhase.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["ProjectPhase"].ToString());
        txtProjectWorkHours.Text = (myReader["WorkHours"].ToString());
        txtProjectPlannedCompletionDate.Text = (myReader["PlannedCompletionDate"].ToString());
        txtProjectComments.Text = (myReader["Comments"].ToString());
    }
    con1.Close();
}

protected void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PROJECTS"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE tbl_projects SET [Date] = @Date, " +
        $"[Number] = @Number, " +
        $"[CustomerName] = @CustomerName, " +
        $"[AccpacPcNo] = @AccpacPcNo, " +
        $"[CRMCaseNo] = @CRMCaseNo, " +
        $"[ProjectDetails] = @ProjectDetails, " +
        $"[TechnicalResourceAssigned] = @TechnicalResourceAssigned, " +
        $"[ProjectPhase] = @ProjectPhase, " +
        $"[WorkHours] = @WorkHours, " +
        $"[PlannedCompletionDate] = @PlannedCompletionDate, " +
        $"[Comments] = @Comments FROM tbl_Projects WHERE ID = @ReqID", con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtProjectDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtProjectNumber.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", txtProjectCustomerName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccpacPcNo", txtProjectAccpacNumber.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRMCaseNo", txtProjectCRMCaseNumber.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDetails", txtProjectDetails.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TechnicalResourceAssigned", txtProjectTechnicalResourceAssigned.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectPhase", txtProjectPhase.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkHours", txtProjectWorkHours.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlannedCompletionDate", txtProjectPlannedCompletionDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", txtProjectComments.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqID", _REQID);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: `The parameterized query '(@ReqID nvarchar(4000))SELECT [id], [Date], [Number], [CustomerN' expects the parameter '@ReqID', which was not supplied.' `
This is the error I am getting now.  Also what do you mean by `vulnerable for SQL Injection`?

Comment: forgot to remove } in sql statement now check this

Comment: in Select and Update Query you directly Refer User Editable Variable called **Request[id]** that makes query vulnerable.

Comment: did u add this line  **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqID", _REQID);** 
and this line  **  myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqID", _REQID );**